# How to apply filter (add_filter) into a get_option in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I have this serialized data into my wp_option table.
I'd like to create a function to retrieve the data (get_option) then apply filter to change the value of "http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/logo.png" into something else...

(146,'theme_mods_theme-child', 'a:9:{i:0;b:0;s:8:"bg_color";s:7:"#ef4036";s:11:"header_logo";s:65:"http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/logo.png";s:14:"menu_no_switch";s:0:"";s:10:"main_color";s:7:"#ef4036";s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:1:{s:11:"header-menu";i:2;}s:9:"copyright";s:77:"nom nom nom nom";s:7:"credits";s:66:"la la la la";s:8:"sidebars";s:51:"Audio1|Audio2|Audio3|Audio4|News1|News2|News3|News4";}', 'yes'),

Answer (score 4):

You can use option_{$option} filter, the value on get_option can be updated like this.

```
add_filter( 'option_theme_mods_theme-child', function( $values ){
    if ( $values ) {
        //do somthing with data
    }
    return $values;
});
```

Find more about option_{$option} filter on  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`apply_filters`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) to add a filter to a variable.

First, get the options array from the database with `get_option`. Then pull out the `header_logo` key and store it in a variable.

Next, add a filter to the variable. Finally, write a function to return the new value and use `add_filter` to register it to your filter.

```
// The header logo
$theme_mods_theme_child_options = get_option('theme_mods_theme-child');

$header_logo = apply_filters( 'my_header_logo_filter', $theme_mods_theme_child_options['header_logo'] );

// Do something with $header_logo

// functions.php or a plugin
function my_header_logo_filter_function(){
    return 'some-new-image.png';
}

add_filter('my_header_logo_filter', 'my_header_logo_filter_function');
```